# How to loop to see objects (1 to 1) of This.questionnaire.Profile at each click (I did not find on the forum) in JavaScript explanation

Tags: javascript, html

I create groups of questions, the parts of the questions are in This.question = {p1: {...}, p2: {...}, p3: {...}, p4: {...}, p5: {...} ect. . (Much more)

how I can do each time I click (button) goes from P1 to the next article ... click => next article => next article (as many as there are questions) (no need for inside of objects just the element pass)

I try: but it shows me that the p2 :

```
for(var question in this.questionnaire.Profil["p2"]){
   this.current=this.questionnaire.Profil["p2"][question];
   console.log(question, " -> " + this.questionnaire.Profil);
   break;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create a loop on `profile`s as well using `Object.values` and `forEach`

```
Object.keys( this.questionnaire.Profil ).forEach( function( profileKey ){
   var profile = this.questionnaire.Profil[ profileKey ];
   for(var question of profile ){ //also observe of instead in
      this.current=question;
      console.log( question );
   }   
});
```

> how I can do each time I click (button) goes from P1 to the next
>   article

So, when a button is clicked get the next profile

```
var currentProfile = "p2";
var allProfiles = Object.keys( this.questionnaire.Profil );
var currentProfileIndex = allProfiles.indexOf( currentProfile );
```

and get the next profile as

```
if ( currentProfileIndex < allProfiles.length - 1 )
{
   var nextProfile = allProfiles[ currentProfileIndex + 1 ];
}
```

Comment: error [ts] The 'values' property does not exist on the 'ObjectConstructor' type

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: not the error and in the code it emphasizes me in red value with the error

Comment: `for(var question in this.questionnaire.Profil["p2"]){
     this.current=this.questionnaire.Profil["p2"][question];
     console.log(question, " -> " + this.questionnaire.Profil);
     break;
    }`

Comment: where there is ["p2"] here that allows me to move on to my next element find how to define the next element to put in place of ["p2"]

Comment: Did you checked the part where I have explained how to find `nextProfile` ?

Comment: where ? 
I do not find